# CSS styles disabled on load (developer tools)

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a set of styles that are not being applied. I am used to overridden styles being crossed out but my styles are showing as if I had disabled them on page load and the styles are not applied on any device. I also can enable them in the firefox dev tools and they work fine.

[image: Screenshot of dev tools - I have not disabled the styles myself]

I have a load of JS going on around this area so I'm willing to accept that is why, but I'm not able to trace it any further without understanding what is happening. I'm looking to get all three disabled styles working (`margin-bottom`, `box-shadow` & `border-radius`).

Of course any help figuring out the whole problem would be appreciated, but primarily I'd like to understand what the behaviour that the dev tools is giving me means.

If it really helps I'll share the site address.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the `width: 200px` attribute being crossed out, the explanation is quite simple: **Inline style attributes will always override CSS attributes.**

The CSS properties you see under `element{}` at the right are those applied by your `style` attribute (embedded in your HTML or set by Javascript). Unless you remove the `width` from the `style` attribute, your CSS `width` will never be applied.

Comment: No as I put in the question I'm looking at the margin-bottom, box-shadow & border-radius, that look like they've been manually disabled.

Comment: @Lucent OK my bad, and exactly what do you see on the Computed tab when you select one of those properties?

Comment: there's a lot in the computed tab, but no sign of the box-shadow & border-radius. some mention of margins but that's not surprising as I know there are some there other margin styles floating about.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you were overriding the styles inline (hard coded or with script), the corresponding style sheet property would have a line through it. In FireBug, assuming that's what that is, the circle with the line means you manually disabled them.

This may be too obvious, but I have to ask, is this an SPA? Have you performed a hard refresh? have you turned off FireBug, cleared cache and tried again?

Comment: This is unfortunately exactly what I thought, but the behaviour is exactly as if I'd disabled but I haven't. I had tried, restarting everything, and have again to be sure. I am not actually sure this has ever worked, I wrote this code a while ago now. what is an SPA?

Comment: Single page application

Comment: have you tried removing and reinstalling Firebug? Does the problem persist with Firebug closed or in other browsers?

Comment: Have you tried switching from windows to mac? (ok, sorry... that was a joke)

Comment: No not an SPA (thanks for that one). I'll be honest I'm not keen to separate this off completely as it's part of a fairly involved DB driven gallery slidshow. My assumption is still it's part of that slideshow that's causing the problem.

Comment: I have no rounding or shadow on any browser or device (inc mobile).. oddly chrome's dev tools (which I hate) don't bother to show the styling rules at all. As if they were not in the css file.

Comment: Run your CSS through a validator to rule out syntax errors https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 0):

Firebug / Firefox dev tools shows lines of css that are commented out as being disabled and allows you to treat them as if you had disabled them.

Comment: This situation only became unsolvable originally due to some bad file management - apologies to those who tried to help. But an interesting firebug feature learnt.